# На Windows puppeteer работает а на Linux нет?

Tags: puppeteer

Есть парсер на puppeteer.
Он отлично работает если его запустить на WINDOWS
Но этот код парсера не работает в Ubuntu 20.04. Вернее работает, но сайт доннор присылает совсем не тот HTML КОД
Думал забанили ip сервера. Но нет. Я подключился через прокси. И все так же. на WINDOWS отлично а Линукс все плохо. Не находит нужный селектор
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: все что угодно. Например, разные версии библиотек (и одна с библиотек содержит "багу"/"особенность"). А может ошибка в коде.

Comment: Код полностью идентичен. Все дело в том, что все работало. Пару дней назад перестало. Так что библиотеки те же. Их никто не переустанавливал

Comment: обновилась убунта, подтянула свежие версии и все.